# File:/// URL won't open PDF or DOCX in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I need to be able to use file:/// URL scheme to load various types of files in an iframe in IE, and I have it working in IE7/8/9 fine (site is setup as a Trusted Site, disabled content disposition sniffing, etc) for a number of files types (txt, png, gif, etc) but it appears anything associated with office or PDF fails with a 404 "File cannot be found" error.  Once again - the file:/// URL scheme works fine for the txt, png, etc files, so I have that part working, it just fails for PDFs, DOCX, even CSV files (on machines with office installed).  Happens in Windows 7, Vista, and XP.  If I change the extension but nothing else, it loads - so if I have file:///test.pdf and change it to file:///test.txt (same file, different extension) it loads fine in the iframe - it loads garbage of course, but it loads fine!

I have heard this relates to content disposition sniffing, so I disabled that, and have also heard that it could relate to issues with DDE, but haven't found a consistent solution that works.

Any thoughts? I have control over the machines this page will need to be accessed by, so I'm fine if it requires a registry tweak, as we have a number of other tweaks that will be deployed as a GPO.

Answer (score 0):

This is first time I see that URL / file path is correct and IE is throwing 404 because of "wrong" file type. But, on the other hand, this is Internet Explorer -- expect everything! :]

Are you 100% sure that you have all the required plugins installed in your Internet Explorer. The fact that you have Office installed changes nothing AFAIK. Maybe your IE suffers lack of plugin for displaying PDFs or Office documents. And that is why, it loads file correctly with changed extension, but not with correct one.

Have you tried putting the very same URL / path into address bar? Do you have the same problems or do they only appear in IFRAME?

Comment: Same problem either way, plugin is installed, filetype opens fine off an http:// URL

Comment: This is really weird and strange. Sorry, I can't help anymore. I thought that newest versions of Internet Explorer doesn't contains such pieces of crap and were burried down with IE 6. But it seems Microsoft can't sleep well, if any version of any of their software doesn't make some pain to at least dozen developers! :|

Comment: Could this be similar to your problem -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215486/iframe-pacman-game-from-worldsbiggestpacman-com-not-working-in-ie9 -- again IFRAME does not work corectly in IE, while works fine in others.